# A javascript recursion problem

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm writing a js recursion function to find all ancestors of an element a user clicked on. my code is like this:

```
/**a global variable.*/
var anc; 

function getAncestors(e){  
 var ele = e.target; 
 var parentName = ele.parentNode.name;    
 anc +=bracket(parentName); 

 if (parentName.toLowerCase() == "undefined" ) return;    
 else getAncestors(parent);     
}
```

I ran it using firefox, but there's an error message in the error console, "Error: ele.parentNode is undefined".

also, when i reset 
anc = ' ';
it didn't work either.

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: Where does the variable `parent` come from? And what does the `bracket()` function do? Is `parent` perhaps another global variable that's set by something else?

Answer (score 4):

1. `parent` is undefined.  You may have meant `ele.parentNode`, but see below.
2. By name convention and by `.target`, I take it `e` is an event.  But you pass `parent`, which probably isn't an event.
3. You probably want to check that `ele.parentNode` is valid before getting it's properties.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at how they implement the [`parents`](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.2/Traversing/parents) function in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

An `undefined` value, per Javascript standards, doesn't *have* a `name` attribute -- so rather than trying to get the `name` in one gulp, just do a `var parent = e.target.parentNode;` and bail out if THAT is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

You should break the recursion like this

```
if(ele.parentNode) return;
```

`parentNode.name` is not supported by firefox

Comment: That should be negated (`if (!ele...`), yes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
var anc = [];

function getAncestors(element) {
  if (element.parentNode) {
    anc.push(element.parentNode);
    getAncestors(element.parentNode);
  }
}
```